# Reading .csv files with different footer row length in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am a complete noob at Python so I apologize if the solution is obvious.
I am trying to read some .csv field data on python for processing. Currently I have:

```
data = pd.read_csv('somedata.csv', sep=' |,', engine='python', usecols=(range(0,10)), skiprows=155, skipfooter=3)
```

However depending on if the data collection was interrupted, the last few lines of the file may be something like:

> #data_end
>
> Run Complete

Or

> Run Interrupted
>
> ERROR
>
> A bunch of error codes

Hence I can't just use skipfooter=3. Is there a way for Python to detect the length of the footer and skip it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first read the content of your file as a plain text file into a Python list, remove those lines that don't contain the expected number of separators, and then transform the list into an IO stream. This IO stream is then passed on to `pd.read_csv` as if it was a file object.

The code might look like this:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# adjust these variables to meet your requirements:
number_of_columns = 11
separator = " |, "

# read the content of the file as plain text:
with open("somedata.csv", "r") as infile:
    raw = infile.readlines()

# drop the rows that don't contain the expected number of separators:
raw = [x for x in raw if x.count(separator) == number_of_columns]

# turn the list into an IO stream (after joining the rows into a big string):
stream = StringIO("".join(raw))

# pass the string as an argument to pd.read_csv():
df = pd.read_csv(stream, sep=separator, engine='python', 
                 usecols=(range(0,10)), skiprows=155)
```

If you use Python 2.7, you have to make replace the first line `from io import StringIO` by the following two lines:

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from cStringIO import StringIO
```

This is so because `StringIO` requires a unicode string (which is not the default in Python 2.7), and because the `StringIO` class lives in a different module in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to simply resort to counting the commas for each line and manually find the last correct one. I'm not aware of a parameter to read_csv to automate that.